# Asynchronous Task only retrieving data in debug mode (android)

Tags: android, debugging, asynchronous, background, rss

I have an android application in which I just want to simply display text from an RSS feed in a list view. The application only retrieves the feed when I run it in debug mode, with breakpoints on certain lines in the Main activity.

I retrieve the feed asynchronously so this could be one of the reasons why this happens, but I'm not quite sure how to make it display the feed instantly when I run the app without the debugger.

**Here is the main activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<String> headlines = new ArrayList<>();
    RetrieveFeed getXML = new RetrieveFeed();

    getXML.execute();

    headlines = getXML.heads();

    // Binding data
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}}
```

**Here is the class which does the background retrieval in the background:**

```
public class RetrieveFeed extends AsyncTask {

URL url;
ArrayList<String> headlines = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList();


@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

    try {
        //does specific stuff here :)

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return headlines;
}

private InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
    try {
        return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> heads()
{
    return headlines;
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to access the data before your `AsyncTask` finishes.

```
getXML.execute();
headlines = getXML.heads();
// you execute your AsyncTask here and try to access it's data
// immediately, without waiting for it to finish execution
```

To fix this, you need to override `onPostExecute()` in your `AsyncTask`, (which is get called after `doInBackground()` finishes) and populate/refresh your `ListView` from there.

You could either make `RetrieveFeed` an inner class of `MainActivity`, so you have direct access to your `ListView`, or implement callback mechanism via an interface.

If you choose the latter, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9963705/3363481) for an example.

To show a `ProgressDialog` during execution, you should override `onPreExecute()` as well. Show your dialog from there and dismiss it in `onPostExecute()`.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25998219/3363481) for an example.